Blockchain - Raydium - Python - Matching Transactions cross wallet
I have been trying to create a program in python to analyze my Pnl of trades subcategorized by wallets that I am copy trading on Raydium. I have tried out two code bases so far and the first returns 0 results (I know I have copy traded the wallet) and I have this one setup through the Solscan API. The other I have been trying to use directly on the solana network (haven't fully set it up I've just been trying to get it to pull transactions for me) and gives me back this error regardless of installing solana through terminal:
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solana.publickey'
First code base:
`import requests
from datetime import datetime

# Raydium AMM Program IDs
RAYDIUM_AMM_PROGRAM_ID = [
    "CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C",
    "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
    "5quBtoiQqxF9Jv6KYKctB59NT3gtJD2Y65kdnB1Uev3h",
    "CAMMCzo5YL8w4VFF8KVHrK22GGUsp5VTaW7grrKgrWqK",
    "routeUGWgWzqBWFcrCfv8tritsqukccJPu3q5GPP3xS",
]

# Function to fetch transaction history for an account
def fetch_transaction_history(account, api_key, limit=100, before=None):
    url = f"https://pro-api.solscan.io/v1.0/account/transactions?account={account}&limit={limit}"
    if before:
        url += f"&before={before}"
    headers = {"accept": "application/json", "token": api_key}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch transaction history for account {account}: {response.status_code}")
        return []

# Function to extract token and amount information from instructions
def extract_token_info(instructions):
    for instruction in instructions:
        if instruction['programId'] in RAYDIUM_AMM_PROGRAM_ID and instruction['type'] == 'swap':
            return instruction['data']
    return None

# Function to filter and normalize transactions
def filter_and_normalize_transactions(transactions):
    valid_transactions = []
    for tx in transactions:
        if tx['status'] == 'Success':
            token_info = extract_token_info(tx['parsedInstruction'])
            if token_info:
                valid_transactions.append({
                    'blockTime': tx['blockTime'],
                    'amountIn': token_info.get('amountIn', 0),
                    'amountOut': token_info.get('amountOut', 0),
                    'tokenAccount': token_info.get('tokenAccount', 'Unknown')
                })
    return valid_transactions

# Function to match buy transactions between your wallet and a copied wallet
def match_buy_transactions(your_trades, copied_trades):
    matched_trades = []
    for copied_trade in copied_trades:
        copied_instruction_data = extract_token_info(copied_trade['parsedInstruction'])
        
        if copied_instruction_data:
            copied_token_account = copied_instruction_data.get('tokenAccount', 'Unknown')
            copied_amount_in = copied_instruction_data.get('amountIn', 0)
            copied_amount_out = copied_instruction_data.get('amountOut', 0)
            
            if copied_amount_in > copied_amount_out:
                for your_trade in your_trades:
                    your_instruction_data = extract_token_info(your_trade['parsedInstruction'])
                    
                    if your_instruction_data:
                        your_token_account = your_instruction_data.get('tokenAccount', 'Unknown')
                        your_amount_in = your_instruction_data.get('amountIn', 0)
                        your_amount_out = your_instruction_data.get('amountOut', 0)
                        
                        if your_amount_in > your_amount_out and copied_token_account == your_token_account:
                            matched_trades.append(your_trade)
                            break
    
    return matched_trades

# Function to calculate PnL from matched buys and your sells
def calculate_pnl(matched_buys, sells):
    pnl = 0
    matched_buys_by_token = {}
    
    for buy in matched_buys:
        token = buy['tokenAccount']
        if token not in matched_buys_by_token:
            matched_buys_by_token[token] = []
        matched_buys_by_token[token].append(buy)
    
    for sell in sells:
        sell_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(sell['blockTime'])
        token = sell['tokenAccount']
        if token in matched_buys_by_token:
            for buy in matched_buys_by_token[token]:
                buy_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(buy['blockTime'])
                if buy_time < sell_time:
                    pnl += sell['amountOut'] - buy['amountIn']
                    matched_buys_by_token[token].remove(buy)
                    break
    return pnl

# Main script
api_key = "My API key here"
your_wallet = "my wallet"
copied_wallets = ["copy traded wallet"]

# Fetch and normalize your trades
your_trades_raw = fetch_transaction_history(your_wallet, api_key)
your_trades = filter_and_normalize_transactions(your_trades_raw)
your_buys = [trade for trade in your_trades if trade['amountIn'] > trade['amountOut']]
your_sells = [trade for trade in your_trades if trade['amountOut'] > trade['amountIn']]

print(f"Your Buys: {your_buys}")
print(f"Your Sells: {your_sells}")

# Dictionary to store PnL categorized by copied wallets
pnl_breakdown = {}

# Fetch trades for copied wallets and calculate PnL categorized by them
for wallet in copied_wallets:
    copied_trades_raw = fetch_transaction_history(wallet, api_key)
    copied_trades = filter_and_normalize_transactions(copied_trades_raw)
    matched_trades = match_buy_transactions(your_buys, copied_trades)
    pnl = calculate_pnl(matched_trades, your_sells)
    pnl_breakdown[wallet] = pnl

# Output the detailed PnL breakdown
for wallet, pnl in pnl_breakdown.items():
    print(f"PnL for trades triggered by copied wallet {wallet}: {pnl}")

# Overall PnL from all categorized trades
overall_pnl = sum(pnl_breakdown.values())
print(f"Overall PnL from copy traded wallets: {overall_pnl}")


Second code base:
import json
import time
import threading
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.publickey import PublicKey

# Constants
EXPLORER_URL_TX = "https://explorer.solana.com/tx/"
ADDRESS_RAYDIUM_AMM = "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8"
ADDRESS_SOLSCAN = "https://api.solscan.io/account?address="

# Solana Client
SOLANA_MAINNET = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
client = Client(SOLANA_MAINNET)

# Initialize variables
resultArr = []
maxTxCount = 10000
txCount = 0
lastSignature = None
rounds = 0

def get_tx_detail(tx_signature):
    tx = client.get_confirmed_transaction(tx_signature)
    if tx['result'] is not None:
        post_token_balances = tx["result"]["meta"]["postTokenBalances"]
        pre_token_balances = tx["result"]["meta"]["preTokenBalances"]
        if post_token_balances != pre_token_balances:
            print(EXPLORER_URL_TX + tx_signature)
            resultArr.append(tx)

# Fetch Raydium transactions
if __name__ == "__main__":
    RaydiumPubKey = PublicKey(ADDRESS_RAYDIUM_AMM)
    while True:
        print("Round-", rounds + 1)
        print("Getting transactions")
        txs = client.get_signatures_for_address(RaydiumPubKey, limit=200, before=lastSignature)['result']
        print("Processing signatures")
        signatures = np.array([tx["signature"] for tx in txs])

        threads = []
        for signature in signatures:
            txCount += 1
            thread = threading.Thread(target=get_tx_detail, args=(signature,))
            threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

        if txCount >= maxTxCount:
            break
        else:
            rounds += 1
            lastSignature = txs[-1]["signature"]
        time.sleep(3)

# Process transaction details
def process_tx(tx):
    tx_signature = tx["result"]["transaction"]["signatures"][0]
    tx_sender = tx["result"]["transaction"]["message"]["accountKeys"][0]
    block_time = tx["result"]["blockTime"]
    slot = tx["result"]["slot"]
    post_token_balances = tx["result"]["meta"]["postTokenBalances"]
    pre_token_balances = tx["result"]["meta"]["preTokenBalances"]
    token_balances = []

    for pre, post in zip(pre_token_balances, post_token_balances):
        change = 0
        if pre["uiTokenAmount"]["uiAmount"] is not None and post["uiTokenAmount"]["uiAmount"] is not None:
            change = post["uiTokenAmount"]["uiAmount"] - pre["uiTokenAmount"]["uiAmount"]
        owner = pre["owner"]
        token = pre["mint"]
        if change != 0:
            token_balances.append({"owner": owner, "token": token, "change": change})

    return {
        "txSignature": tx_signature,
        "sender": tx_sender,
        "blockTime": block_time,
        "slot": slot,
        "tokenBalances": token_balances
    }

processed_tx_arr = [process_tx(tx) for tx in resultArr]

# Map token mint address to readable token names
mint_dic = {}
for tx in processed_tx_arr:
    for token_balance in tx["tokenBalances"]:
        token = token_balance["token"]
        if token not in mint_dic:
            req = Request(ADDRESS_SOLSCAN + token, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            data = json.loads(urlopen(req).read())
            mint_dic[token] = data["data"]["tokenInfo"]["name"]
            time.sleep(1)

for tx in processed_tx_arr:
    for token_balance in tx["tokenBalances"]:
        token_balance["token"] = mint_dic.get(token_balance["token"], token_balance["token"])

# Normalize token transactions
normalized_tx_arr = []
for tx in processed_tx_arr:
    for token_change in tx["tokenBalances"]:
        normalized_tx_arr.append({
            'txSignature': tx["txSignature"],
            'sender': tx["sender"],
            'blockTime': tx["blockTime"],
            'slot': tx["slot"],
            'owner': token_change["owner"],
            'token': token_change["token"],
            'change': token_change["change"]
        })

# Print normalized transactions
for tx in normalized_tx_arr:
    print(tx)
`your text`
# Now, you can implement PnL calculations and subcategorization based on your specific needs.`



It looks like the code you're using is for the older version of solana. From their latest code, they are using solders.pubkey.Pubkey from the library solders instead. Another way you can workaround this issue is to downgrade your solana version to when solana.publickey.PublicKey was supported using the command
pip install solana=="<older version number here>"

From this answer , looks like version 0.16.0 supports solana.publickey.PublicKey class
